# Remote Node.js typescript debugging in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, webstorm

I am trying to debug my NodeJS backend written in TypeScript and then transpiled to a single JavaScript file via webpack. Here's my webpack config.

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var node_externals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
entry: './app.ts',
target: 'node',
externals: [node_externals()],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bin.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate        : '[absolute-resource-path]',
    devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]?[hash]'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'}
    ]
},
devtool: 'source-map',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
}
}
```

Sourcemaps are generated correctly and debug is working if Node instance is local. The problem is, i am running my node instance in docker container, so i have to debug it via remote debug. And it's just not working(which is understandable, 'cause WebStorm has no idea about typescript files and all stuff). The question is, is it possible to make this work?